# How to implement window with ask for username and password in Sql Membership provider

Tags: c#, silverlight, sqlmembershipprovider

I use tutorial from [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Connecting-to-the-SqlMembership-model-through-Silverlight-and-WCF.aspx) to create SQL Membership Provider. But I don't know how to implement functionality, that when user open my Silverlight application appear window where he must put correct user name and password and when he click login button some function check sql db that he is valid user?

Any idea how to implement this ?